# 10Gbase-T vs 10Gbase-TX

Tags: 10gbase

At 1 Gbit, 1000BaseT (4-pair UTP, Full duplex, IEEE 802.3ae) was supposedly different from 1000Base-TX (2 pair TIA/EIA 854), but at 10G, it seems that manufacturers are using 10Gbase-T and 10Gbase-TX interchangeably. Are they actually the same?  If one manufacturer specifies 10Gbase-T for an endpoint and you use a 10Gbase-TX SFP+ on the switch, is it actually compatible?  I cannot find an actual standard for 10Gbase-TX.

Thank you!

Comment: TIA's 1000BASE-TX was so unsuccessful and is so obscure that it's very hard to find the specifications today... And 10GBASE-TX isn't a thing, as Ricky correctly states.

Comment: Any idea why some manufacturers don't even list 10GBase-T as a transceiver type, only 10GBase-TX?

Comment: No, that's nonsense. I've seen all kinds of silliness though, "10GBASE-BX", "10BASE-TX", "100BASE-T", etc. Those vendors don't seem to know what they're doing.

Answer (score 4):

You can't find a standard for "TX" because there's no such thing. 10Gbase-T is defined by 802.3an-2006. I've never seen anyone call it "10Gbase-TX".

('tho there is a 10Gbase-T1 for automotive applications [802.3ch-2020])